# HTTPS Cookie and Cache manager in Jmeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I am trying to do performance testing for an application. Manually if I try to launch the application, it will take around 7 seconds to load. But in Jmeter, even after checking 'Clear cookies in each iteration' and 'clear cache each iteration', I can see the average time was 279 milli seconds only.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you comparing?  *launch the application* can include many operations

Comment: Yes. Manually launch will take around 7-9 sec. When I replayed in Jmeter, that transaction is showing in less than 1 millisecond.